# How to move image in the circular motion by having start and end degree as same using css3?

Tags: css

```
.ball{
  position:absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 300px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: yellow;
 border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-animation: balls 4s linear;
 animation: balls 4s linear;

-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes balls {
 0% { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px)  rotate(0deg); }
 100%   { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px)  rotate(360deg); }
}


@keyframes balls {
 from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
 to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
 }
```

The above was my code to rotate in the circuar motion. I want my start and end degree as same and also it should rotate in the circular motion. Please help me with the solution to my problem

Comment: [animation-direction?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction)

Answer (score 0):

I would use this code to rotate a image (it never stops):

```
.image {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
-webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

If you just want 360 degrees, delete the word infinite and it should work.

EDIT: Here a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Ugc5g/)

Answer (score 0):

Have found solution for my problem.

By having 'from' degree we can calculate the 'to' degree as 'from+359' so it will rotate a whole round by having the single degree